# initialize case class from Vector

Tags: scala

I'd like to initialize a case class, or normal class from vector of values.

Example code I have now looks like this:

```
class P(parameters : Vector[String]) {
   val a: String = parameters(0)
   val b: String = parameters(1)
   val c: String = parameters(2)
}
```

I initialize this with

```
P(Vector[String]("1", "2", "3"))
```

but it would be better if I could do have a case class:

```
case class P (a: String, b: String, c: String)
```

and be still able to initialize it with a given vector - not necessairly via constructor. Also I'd like to support a case where Vector has less elements than the object to be created:

```
P(Vector[String]("1"))
```

I'm looking for a scala way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can define an additional constructor in your case class:

```
case class P(a: String, b: String, c: String) {
  def this(parameters: Vector[String]) =
    this(parameters(0), parameters(1), parameters(2))
}
```

What should happen if you call this with a `Vector` that contains less than three elements?

Comment: That would be fine with just 3 arguments, but I need like 20 of them :)

Comment: Ok, why didn't you explain that in your question?

Comment: @MarcinCylke In that case shapless might help with case classes: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#generic-representation-of-sealed-families-of-case-classes you just need to convert the Vector to HList.

Comment: I might also add that case classes have the limitation of 22 parameters, so do not move above 20 too much.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you are looking for something like this:

```
case class P (a: String, b: String, c: String)
object P {
  def apply(v: Vector[String]): P = {
    //your code to create P, probably
    P(v(0), v(1), v(2))
  }
}
```